# Personal Time Tracking report using Atlassian Jira

Tags: jira, reporting, timekeeping

I'm a software developer and I'm asked to log my time in Atlassian Jira for each of the subtasks we have in all the open stories. Sometimes we are in rush and I forget to log some time in the many subtasks.

I wonder if there is any Jira utility I can use to get the overall number of logged time in a day, or maybe a query to run in the *search bar* (see image below) to find all the sub-tasks in which I logged some time.

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: "I wonder if there is any tool" doesn't comply with "This site is NOT about... Tool recommendations". Hope this is clearer. I was just suggesting to rephrase the question to be less tool-oriented and more management-oriented. For tool recommendations you have https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Tiago Cardono Got it! I mad a minor change. I hope it suffices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **worklogAuthor** and **worklogDate** parameters for your needs.

Your query will be like:

```
project = "My Project" AND worklogAuthor = currentUser() AND worklogDate = now()
```

You will get all issues in which you logged some time today.

Answer (score 3):

One of the free option available is to use the browser extension named Jira Assistant available in below url. This extension has lot more useful features which not only helps to generate report, but also help to log your work on daily basis with notifications, calendar integrations and lot more cool features which helps both managers and team members in their daily activity:

For Chrome users: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jira-assistant/momjbjbjpbcbnepbgkkiaofkgimihbii?src=sof

For Firefox users: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/jira-assistant/